# Algoritmo en el cambio de network Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Hola tengo un  BroadcastReceiver que me retorna

```
Log.i("Network", "Network connected : " + ni.getTypeName()); WIFI o MOBILE
```

y otro metodo que me retorna en caso de ser WIFI su

```
Log.i("Network", "Name " + ssid);
```

hay un método que se debe ejucutar si `ni.getTypeName()` es `WIFI` y de repente cambia a `MOBILE` y viceversa y si esta en `WIFI` y el `SSID` cambia igualmente ejecutar este metodo.

Comment: Explica mejor cual es el problema. Amplía la información de la pegunta para que te podamos ayudar.

Comment: @Oundroni Que se debe ejecutar un metodo onChangeNetwork si de red MOBILE paso a WIFI y viceversa.  Osea que se ejecute el metodo si detecta el cambio. Ya que puedo estar conectado 1 hora a red WIFI y de repente cambio a MOBILE este justo momento onChangeNetwork debe ejecutarse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede usar estos 2 metodos para detectar el tipo de red:

```
public static boolean isConnectedWifi(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
}

public static boolean isConnectedMobile(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;
}
```

Para determinar el cambio, puedes definir dos constantes para definir los dos tipos de red:

```
private final static int WIFI_ACTIVA = 0 ;
private final static int MOVIL_ACTIVA = 1 ;
```

y otro determinar el tipo actual activo y la última red detectada:

```
private int RED_ACTIVA = 0 ;
private int ULTIMA_RED_ACTIVA = 0 ;
```

El BroadCastReceiver debe revisar constantemente el tipo:

```
if(isConnectedWifi(getApplicationContext()){
    RED_ACTIVA = WIFI_ACTIVA;
}else if(isConnectedMobile(getApplicationContext()){
   RED_ACTIVA = MOVIL_ACTIVA ;
}else{
   RED_ACTIVA = -1; //No existe red activa WIFI o MOVIL.
}
```

Al final simplemente comparas el valor de la última red activa.

```
if(ULTIMA_RED_ACTIVA != RED_ACTIVA){
     //RED ACTIVA CAMBIO!
     switch(RED_ACTIVA) {
            case WIFI_ACTIVA:
             //RED ACTIVA CAMBIO A WIFI! 
             break; 
            case MOVIL_ACTIVA :
             //RED ACTIVA CAMBIO A MOVIL! 
             break; 
     }
}
```

Almacenas el valor de la "última red activa":

```
ULTIMA_RED_ACTIVA = RED_ACTIVA
```

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien el planteamiento de tu pregunta, esto te puede ayudar.

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html?hl=es